# What is the complexity of an array that find minimum of an array

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity, recursion

```
ALGORITHM Min1 (A[0..n - 1])
//Input: An array A [0..n — 1 ] of real numbers
if n = 1 
 return A [0]
else temp <— Min1 (A[0..n — 2])
if temp <= A [n — 1] 
  return temp
else return A [n — 1]
```

What is the recursion statement of this algorithm? What is the complexity?
What is the asymptotic analysis of this algorithm?

Comment: @hardmath i believe i fixed.

Comment: @hardmath, you are right, I fixed it now

Comment: Okay, it is fixed regarding the typo in the code.  Now please turn your hand to the edits called for by @saulspatz.  In its present form the Question is not up to the content standards of Math.SE.  You should provide some context for the three things you ask about (recursion statement, complexity, and "asymptotic analysis").  If the real problem is learning the definitions of these terms, then you should back up and address those issues before asking Readers to help you apply them to the code for `Min1`.

Comment: $T(n) = T(n-1) + \mathcal{O}(1), T(1) = c, T(n) \in \mathcal{O}(n)$, and in this form this question belongs to stackoverflow. And your code need some work,too.